# Excel VBScript Copy and Paste cell values to end of another list

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a table with cell values and would like to copy them to a range on another worksheet. The script below is working for the copy and paste part, but I would like to have the information paste to the end of the list each time and not overwrite information already there.

```
Set excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set info = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jcampos\Google Drive\Standings Excel\Standings.xlsm")

info.Worksheets("XML").Range("DATA").Copy

info.Worksheets("Gameday Info").Range("A2").PasteSpecial -4163

info.save
info.Application.Quit
```

Is there a way to make it append to the bottom of the list instead of overwriting information?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change Range("A2") to reference last row.

```
lastrow = info.Worksheets("Gameday Info").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
info.Worksheets("Gameday Info").Range("A" & lastrow).PasteSpecial -4163
```

See other ways to [reference last row](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba).